# Can a Winforms interop UserControl merge its menus with a VB6 container form's menu bar?

Tags: c#, winforms, vb6, activex, vb6-migration

I am trying to migrate a VB6 UserControl to managed code. The original control has a set of standard menus (File, Help, etc) which are merged in to the menu bar of its container form (an ordinary VB6 form) at runtime.

The control is now rewritten in C#, and registered as an ActiveX control which can be dropped on a Visual Basic 6 form in the VB6 IDE. The next step is to populate the form's menu bar by merging in the UserControl's MenuStrip menus with the container's menubar.

Is this possible? Can an interop UserControl merge its menus into the menu bar of its container (as could be done with VB6 UserControls)?

Comment: The MainMenu component is available in WinForms, you have to get it from the ToolBox (Choose Items...), select it then search it in the ToolBox (with the Search bar). It won't be available anymore in .Net 5 (and, IIRC, in .Net Core 3.0+)

Comment: Are there any examples available demonstrating how to use this for interop?

Comment: IMO, you should search for examples that show how to migrate a VB6 Form to a .Net Form.

Comment: I doubt the .NET menus are the same type of object as the VB6 ones. If they all implement the same interface, maybe, but doubtful. If you can create actual VB6 menu objects from within .NET, that has a greater chance of working.

Comment: Our ActiveX frame window is written in C++ and VB6 OCX menus are compatible.

Comment: @StayOnTarget The menu-merging process is independent of the object types. It's done calling IOleInPlaceFrame::InsertMenus() on the container, and with some other low-level trickery.